# How to export a gantt chart in pdf or png format using taskjuggler and/or org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf, project, exporting

I managed to get taskjuggler up and running along emacs/org-mode. After reading the manual entries [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/taskjuggler/ox-taskjuggler.html) and [here](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-taskjuggler.html) I can export my project into html but I cannot export the Gantt chart into pdf, as hinted at the end of [this section](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-taskjuggler.html#org759b833).

The workflow seems to be 1) export the project into a `.tjp` file and then 2) use the GUI to do `File->Print`. However, the version that I am using `tj3 (TaskJuggler) 3.7.1` does not have a GUI as far as I know. I have tried to look for a command that would allow me to export the tjp file into pdf, e.g., [export](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/SS03/19560-P/Docs/Taskjuggler/index-7.html#ss7.5) but without luck.

I am looking for a solution that allows me to obtain a Gantt Chart in a format which can be inserted in a document, although I prefer `pdf` format and to be able to do it from inside emacs org-mode. Thank you in advance.

**Update**

Apparently the standard way to achieve this is to export the html into pdf using a web browser or packages available in linux distros, e.g. wkhtmltoimage and wkhtmltopdf. However, the main problems that I find with these solutions are that 1) for long projects they partially hide the project and show a frozen scrollbar (major issue), and 2) they do not isolate the gantt chart (minor)

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert by any means but one partial solution is proposed here:

- https://groups.google.com/g/taskjuggler-users/c/MCs8jz-T4nQ/m/VCOcjc4lqp4J

Basically they say to print the page from a web browser while visiting the
`.html` file generated by `org-taskjuggler-export-process-and-open`.

However, at least on Firefox the generated `pdf` skips the colors and arrows,
rendering the result kind of useless. And the general workarounds seem
unnecessarily complicated.

I'm using `tj3` same as you, and `man tj3` does not even mention the word `pdf`.

I hope they come up with a less hacky solution.

Comment: These are some relevant options indeed, thanks. I had no good results when printing from within firefox. The other software mentioned in the post, wkhtmltoimage and wkhtmltopdf, worked better but 1) for long projects they partially hide the project and show a frozen scrollbar (major issue), and 2) they do not isolate the gantt chart (minor)

Answer (score 0):

The process is:

- export the Org mode file (say `foo.org`) to a `tjp` file (`foo.tjp`).
- process the `tjp` file with tj3: `tj3 foo.tjp
- view the resulting HTML (`Plan.html`) file with a browser (both Firefox and Chrome worked for me).
- Print from the browser to PDF, but make sure to first open `More settings` and select the `Background graphics` (Chrome) or `Print backgrounds` (Firefox) option. Then click `Save`.

It's probably possible to do the last two steps through a CLI command, so that it could be done from inside Emacs, but I don't know how to do that off the top of my head.

EDIT: I don't know about Firefox but Chrome can print to PDF from the command line with this bash command:

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome --headless --print-to-pdf file://$PWD/Plan.html
```

You might have to change the path to the `chrome` executable.